# How to print a part of element. Target an element,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a printbutton to my shops basket - but I only want to print the body element. Is this possible, to target the specific element with Jquery and vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS style for print... and hide all none body elements in print.css file

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="./style-print.css"/>
```

and now when you click for print that page , css automatically apply to print and just you see what you want.
This is simplest way that use CSS.. you can also use javascript

Comment: ah thats perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Of course:  (via Javascript)

1. Get content of an element:
   var content = document.body;
2. Print them:
   print(content);